# Unable to change the css properties of a paragraph in a div tag

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I wanted to make a function that could change the font-size and text-align properties of a paragraph present within a div tag that executes on pressing a button.

```
function acknowledge()
{
  document.getElementById('centretext').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('button1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('centretext').style.font-size = "99%";
  document.getElementById('centretext').style.text-align = "left";
}
```

Its original properties are:

```
#centretext
{
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: Merriweather;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:bolder;
}
```

Yet when the button is clicked, nothing happens. If I remove the last 2 lines of the function (i.e, the ones that change the properties), then the first two execute fine. What am I doing wrong?
Edit: The div:

```
<div id = "centre">
      <p id="centretext">
        You are a cell.
        <br>
        It's the survival of the fittest.
        <br>
        <br>
        To survive, you must divide, grow and evolve.
      </p>

      <p id="centretext2">
      </p>

      <button class ="buttonformat" id="button1" type="button" onclick="acknowledge()"> OK </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML also, or even better a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where we can reproduce your problem

Comment: @JakubJankowski Sorry, not used a fiddle before, should I include all the code?

Comment: You do not have to include *all* of the code, paste there as much as needed for your error to show there.

Comment: Well, I got my answer, so don't think it's necessary anymore, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    document.getElementById('centretext').style.fontSize = "99%";
    document.getElementById('centretext').style.textAlign = "left";
```

Comment: Oh, it was the hyphen. Is there a reason the css property has one and changing it with javascript doesn't, or is it purely arbitrary?

Comment: It is obviously not arbitrary at all. CSS property is not JS style object's property. Moreover, JS property doesn't accept dash.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('centretext').style.font-size = "99%";
document.getElementById('centretext').style.text-align = "left";

document.getElementById('centretext').style.fontSize = "99%";
document.getElementById('centretext').style.textAlign = "left";